# Web site project login against separate database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use the Visual Studio 2010 - and I'd like to create a ASP.NET Website - however I would like to check the login against a separate database and not the .mdf file because I need a bit more flexibility and the access to the remaining items in my database.

Does anyone of you have a good solution how I could achieve that?

Edit: The database which I have is a SQL Server 2008 R2 database, if that matters.

Comment: If you use Membership you can initialize a new database using aspnet_regsql and simply change the connection string.

Comment: How can I set up my web site project to use the Membership. I jus tried the aspnet_regsql - and it added a couple of tables to my base database. Now I'd need to connect to that database on the server abroad - and combine the new tables ( user informations ) with my previous user informations saved in my old tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are using a web application in ASP.net 4.0 (which I believe is the default for VS2010).

In the web.config file, under connection strings, by default there is a connection named "ApplicationServices", this connection string can be changed to another database.

To setup a database with the tables needed for ASP.net Membership, you will need to use a tool called Aspnet_regsql.exe. [More information on aspnet_regsql.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862.aspx)

But, it sounds as though you may need more experience in general with ASP.net around connections string and memberships and profiles etc. with a little more knowledge of connection strings etc, it would be clearer to you. The [tutorials on the ASP.net site](http://www.asp.net/web-forms) are always a good place to start.

Learning a little more about asp.net, you may find that you change you mind and instead of requiring a separate database, you may discover that things like "database deployments" etc may help.

Comment: Could you explain your last sentence. I'm no native speaker and I'm afraid I could not comprehend the whole meaning of it. Thanks.

Comment: No problem @theXs I've reworded the last sentence.

Comment: @theXs: Here is another article - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/08/25/423703.aspx

Comment: That's a good article @theXs, ScottGu is an authority on ASP.net - so his site is a great resource. Though watch out, the article is quite old, so not everything may apply.. thought I haven't had a chance to read it myself.